# Converting a singular variable regression to multi-variable regression in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Note: I didn't write the code, here is the code I'm trying to modify [this](https://gist.github.com/balzer82/b5cac8fb214e0b52efa0ea7b8a058681) and 
my repository is [here](https://github.com/itisyeetimetoday/reggression).

I'm currently trying to convert a singular variable regression to a multi-variable DNN regression. Line 76 in `regressor_full.py` always returns an error about incompatible shape. I've changed the input to the shape of 11, however, I don't know to change the output layer to 11 too.

```
Line 76 : feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('X', shape=(11,))]
```

However, I'm sure that the input and output tensors aren't the only 2 things that have to be changed. Could you guys help me with adapting the repo? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adapt the regressor for 11 targets/outputs, change the value of label_dimension to 11 as follows [Line #97 in your code]:

```
regressor = skflow.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                label_dimension=11,
                hidden_units=hidden_layers,
                model_dir=MODEL_PATH,
                dropout=dropout,
                config=test_config)
```

Successful training log:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have updated the repo with the label_dimension= 11 edit. How when I update the code and run it, I get this error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: dnn/dnn/hiddenlayer_0_activation
         [[{{node dnn/dnn/hiddenlayer_0_activation}}]]
I've tried decreasing the learning rate and generating new data as suggested by other people, but it doesn't resolve the error. Here is the full error: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RN7PrNvYgGhiAgV0YxPD37APtnWRubhXrXXT2hJlAAw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The code works perfectly without any error with tensorflow 1.14.0. I changed the label_dimensions=11 along with feature_columns value as follows: `feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("X", dimension=11)]` However, it also works for numeric_column as you used.

Comment: Here is my update online notebook. https://notebooks.azure.com/stanleylg/projects/reg-dnn The online notebook has both feature column versions(1  is commented out). I still get the same error despite the fact that I install tensorflow 1.14.0 in the first cell.

Comment: I have attached my successful training log for 10 epochs in the comment above. Sorry, i'm using tensorflow_gpu 1.14.0.and never faced any error.

Comment: Okay I will try with a GPU when I get home.  I was using cpu. If it works with gpu I will accept your answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Okay, it works on the GPU for some odd reason. How do I add an optimizer? I tried changing this line: regressor = skflow.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns,
    label_dimension=11,
    hidden_units=hidden_layers,
    model_dir=MODEL_PATH,
    dropout=dropout,
    config=test_config,
    activation_fn = tf.nn.relu,
    optimizer  = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
). To add the AdamOptimizer and learning rate, but I gett an error saying NotFoundError: restorinf from checkpoint failed.

Comment: You should read error more carefully: 'NotFoundError: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not alter`.
That means your previous stored checkpoint is created without any optimizer (default optimizer is None). Therefore, when you try with optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate) and restore old checkpoint, mismatch happened due to different configuration. Deleting old checkpoints in \DNNRegressors\11_11_D00\ directory will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you. For some odd reason my gpu utilization is currently 1-4% with 75% cpu even though I’m running on a 1060 with tf-gpu. Do you get the same low gpu usage?